# Using typedefs appropriately to avoid "typedef contamination"

Tags: c++, typedef

I'm developing certain features for a larger encompassing project and the "features" I'm working on are some classes put together from which certain functions might be used globally in the main project.

For readability, I've typedef some common (and lengthy) types at my side to be used across my classes. Since most of these types are relatively common and likely used with other meanings, I don't want my typedefs to spill into the main project where different typedefs might be used.

What is then the best approach to ensure my typedefs are "cleanly" defined and not "contaminating" (I'm not sure if this term is used for typedefs too) the project's general typedef pool?

I've so far only had idea of making the typedefs private for each class and essentially redefining typedefs across my classes. Doesn't sound too good I suppose?

Comment: put them into a `namespace` ?

Comment: Put your typedefs (as well as your types and functions) into a namespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You can limit related `typedef`'s in namespaces.
- You can put the `typedef`'s being used in just 1 class into that class.
- If a typedef is used in just few files, add the typedef in `.cpp` file.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use namespaces. So instead of typing:

```
typedef int my_project_my_int;
```

you type

```
namespace my_project {
    typedef int my_int;
}
```

and refer it as `my_project::my_int`.

From within classes defined in the same namespace, you can just refer it as `my_int`. If you want to refer your colleagues type, you can always use `his_project::my_int`.

If you are paranoid, refer it as `::my_project::my_int` and `::his_project::my_int`